# Which command can add numbers to give me new number?

Tags: command-line

This is what I need the command for : We are in year 1970, if we add 5 000 000 000 seconds, what year are we in now ?

Sorry for my question and how it's formulated. I know it's terrible and english is my 3rd language

Comment: This looks like a homework question. But have a look at a [Unix TimeStamp  site](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/) and you get the result `06/11/2128 @ 8:53am (UTC)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unix timestamps starts at "January 1, 1970" so we only need to get the date of '5000000000' in timestamp:

```
$ date -d '@5000000000' +%Y
2128
```

> UNIX Epoch time, is a system for describing a point in time. It is the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970.